# Flash audio fallback loops on short sounds

Tags: html, flash, html5-audio

Our literacy web site for kids with disabilities provides beginning books for readers of all ages. We include the ability to read books aloud using mp3s files generated on the server. We use HTML5 audio on browsers that support it, and fallback to Flash on those that don't. Over 4% of our users have JavaScript disabled so we can't rely on html5 shims that are available.

The implementation works fine except that very short mp3 files play over and over instead of only once as expected. You can hear an annoying example here: http://tarheelreader.org/2012/01/19/the-m-book/?voice=child. To hear the looping you'll need to use Firefox or IE to make it fall back to Flash.

I'm using player_mp3_mini.swf for fallback. With code like this:

```
<object class="flashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/theme
    /player_mp3_mini.swf" width="1" height="1">
  <param name="movie" value="/theme/player_mp3_mini.swf" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#ff0000" />
  <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3={{{eurl}}}&amp;autoplay=1" />
</object>
```

The mp3 file for that first page is 2756 bytes, the second page that does not loop is 2653 so not every short file repeats. I have experimented with the `byteslimit` variable but that has no effect.

I'm looking for a fix, workaround, alternative, anything to fix this problem without requiring JavaScript for every user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your 1-c.mp3 MP3 file with the mini player (even with the normal player version that supports the "loop=0" parameter to control looping) and the Flash player keeps looping as you describe.

I could reproduce this on a local HTML page, so I re-encoded the mp3 (I used Audacity, kept the 32kb but in constant bitrate). The file changed from 2.8kb to 5.6kb but then it played without looping in the mini player.
So I think you need to re-encode the MP3s that are looping, maybe at the cost of a few more kb. Or eventually find another MP3 Flash player that handles small MP3 better.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Yes, I had seen that if the files get bigger they don't loop but that could just be because they changed size. The page 2 sound is actually shorter than page 1 but it doesn't loop. So, it isn't simply length. Creating a static page for experimentation is a good idea.